# Intuition of how free electron moves in superconductor?

Tags: electrons, electric-current, electrical-resistance, superconductivity

I imagine some of the valence electrons clashes with incoming traffic which arise as electrical resistance in wiring at room temperature, how would these electrons move in superconductor which results in almost zero resistance?  What causes them to move in common direction? Assume no doping, other EMP interference from outside, thickness of wire is same throughout and density of atoms is evenly spread out in the wire.

Comment: -"incoming traffic"? - There are no free electrons in the superconducting state. - The resistance is not "almost" but exactly zero in a superconductor.